# python reading entire paragraph rather then reading lines

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
with open(root_dir+"/trials/classify/training_queries.txt","r") as f:
        queries = f.readlines()
        #queries = f.read()
```

Above code reads line by line content from file and gives result for each line for my case.

**I wanted to display result for entire file content(reading entire para in once), what is the function for that?**

I thought `queries = f.read()` will help but it consider character by character.

**Update**

sample input:

```
Hell, the Orioles' Opening Day game could easily be the largest in history
if we had a stadium with 80,000 seats. But unfortunely the Yards (a
definitely excellent ballpark) only holds like 45,000 with 275 SRO spots.
Ticket sales for the entire year is moving fast. Bleacher seats are almost
gone for every game this year. Athist does not believe in any religion whether hinduis islam or chirstianism
```

output scenario:

For readLine() - it was processing line by line

What I want to do is considering entire file content.

code snippet:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #CallDomainDetection().callDomainDetection(sys.argv[1])
    root_dir = os.getcwd()
    query_no = 1
    with open(root_dir+"/trials/classify/training_queries.txt","r") as f:
        #queries = f.readlines()  # this processes line in files
        queries = f.read()    # now it consider each character. 
    for qu in queries:
        CallDomainDetection().callDomainDetection(qu)
        if query_no == 40:
            break
        query_no += 1
```

Comment: Please post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: From your question it appears that the file contains exactly one paragraph. Is that true?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I added the file content and code snippet.

Comment: that does look like one paragraph to me.

Comment: @WeaselFox: the file content is seperated by new line too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f.read()` is what you want. You probably need to split it by two newlines for dividing it into paragraphs  - `split('\n\n')`. What you describe sounds like youre iterating over the string itself - which would mean char by char iteration.

Comment: did you mean? ` queries = f.readlines()
    for p in paragraphs(queries.split('\n\n')): print repr(p)`

Comment: `queries = f.read().split('\n\n')` - IF paragraph means what I think it means. You have not defined what you mean by that term yet.

Answer (score 2):

`queries = f.read()` does read the entire file into the string `queries`. Only if you iterate over that string, you'll get individual characters (as in `for c in queries:`).

Do

```
with open(root_dir+"/trials/classify/training_queries.txt","r") as f:
    queries = f.read()
    print(queries)
```

and see that `queries` is a single string.

Comment: thanks, but that I already mentioned. Here it consider each characters for processing

Comment: @user123: Please re-read the second sentence of my answer. The `for` loop breaks your paragraph (`queries`) into single characters (`qu`). Remove the `for` loop and work on `queries` directly after having `.read()` the file.

Answer (score 2):

You must define a “paragraph” as the string formed by joining a
nonempty sequence of nonseparator lines, separated from any adjoining paragraphs
by nonempty sequences of separator lines.

```
def paragraphs(lines, is_separator=str.isspace, joiner=''.join):
   paragraph = [ ] 
   for line in lines:
     if is_separator(line):
       if paragraph:
         yield joiner(paragraph)
         paragraph = [ ]
     else:
      paragraph.append(line)
   if paragraph:
       yield joiner(paragraph)
if __name__ == '__main__':
 with open(root_dir+"/trials/classify/training_queries.txt","r") as f:
   queries = f.readlines()
   for p in paragraphs(queries): print repr(p)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but it gives error `for p in paragraphs(queries.splitlines(True)):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`

Comment: @user123 i edit answer again you must remove `splitlines` it works good !

Comment: it does not help. what Weasel has suggested is working

Comment: it still gives result for each line